# why image in background-image is rapeating?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, background

i am working on a project in which i have to make a webpage of photographs .tag it open the image  what can  when i work on a project i try  to put image in `background-image`of`body`but it repeat the image .i want to show image once.

```
<body background-image="ali.gpj">please</body>
```

Comment: you can use This:

      `body { background-image: url("ali.gpj"); background-repeat: no-repeat; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat